# Pin tablix row to the bottom of the page on SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, position, ssrs-tablix, subreports

I am trying to print multiple SSRS reports in bulk using subreports. Since there is no way to display subreport header and footer on the main report i need to be able to display header and footer information i.e. company logo, address (header), invoice total in the subreport body. I would like last row of the tablix that contains invoice information to be pinned to the bottom of the page. Counting rows and adding "spacer" row will not work b/c there are comments field that can grow and shrink significantly. is there a way to determine an absolute position of the report element at the time it's printed i.e. text box "order comments" location x,y height H. ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could achieve this is to actually add a space break (not in the tablix) in the report itself. This would be a true, static break in the report, for every page. It would look something like:

```
                                          Header

Tablix -- - - - - - -  -- - - - -- - - - - - - -- - --  - - -

                            [white space- insert items here]

Tablix  - - -- - - -- - - -- - - - - - - - - -- - -  --- - - -

                                          Footer
```

Comment: Static break will not work for my purposes. I need the invoice totals to be pinned to the bottom of the page. The "white space" height will vary from invoice (subreport) to invoice.

Comment: Could you illustrate your issue and the desired result, if possible?